# Windows 10 Pro doesn't understand 'net server' commands

Tags: networking, windows-10, command-line

I have a customer's computer running Windows 10.0.15063 Pro.  If they run "net statistics server", it fails with:

```
The syntax of this command is:
NET STATISTICS
[WORKSTATION]
```

Why would it not understand NET STATISTICS SERVER?  In trying to reproduce this on another Windows 10 Pro computer, I tried uninstalling SMB, but that gives a system error 55, not the result shown above.  So I reinstalled SMB and stopped the server service.  Then when I ran NET STATISTICS SERVER, it says the server service is stopped and asks if I want to start it.  So that's not the problem either.  It sounded to me like maybe it was a home edition of Windows 10, but I confirmed that it is "Windows 10 Pro".  So what could be causing it to behave as if there's no server functionality?

Comment: You are sure this client is connected to a server?  Did you verify the server service is running on this client machine?  The documentation on the command indicates, "Used without parameters, net statistics lists the running services for which statistics are available.", which means statistics on the Server service isn't available.  This means you have a client configuration issue.

Comment: NET STATISTICS SERVER does not require you to be connected to a server, it returns statistics for the server service on the computer you run the command on.  As I mentioned, stopping the server service does not reproduce this problem.  I'm trying to figure out why the NET command wouldn't understand server commands at all, as opposed to returning errors for them like it does when the server service is stopped.

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft official document state as below:

**Syntax**

net statistics [{workstation | server}]

**Parameters**

workstation   : Displays statistics for the local Workstation service.

server   : Displays statistics for the local Server service.

net help   command   : Displays help for the specified net command.

When you run net statistics server command, the output is above like yours, it indicates that there is no server service running on your computer and your computer is only running as workstation instead of Server.

Here is comparison on Windows Server and Windows 10 1709 client
[image]